# React Native android cannot refresh

Tags: android, react-native

At begin, I can refresh the app by double tap 'r', but after I install several SDKs, I can't refresh the app directly, and I can't open the dev-menu either.

After I tried several ways, I found out I have to set the bundle to the local folder 'assets' by this command:

curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"

I still didn't know why this happened and want to try to figure out this issue. It seems I cannot enter the debug mode or something else happened.

I remembered this happened after I install the Facebook SDK.

Did anyone had meet this situation?

Comment: did you try restarting the react-native server?

Comment: Please hit the URL on your Browser and check is it giving you any response or not if it is giving a response that means your server is running.

Comment: Yes, the server is running, and actually, I can refresh iOS app successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the root cause, and it's a stupid mistake.

I built up an app with release mode, but I didn't notice that. So the app always got crash without adding the local bundle, and there was no debug menu for sure.